# Where can I get the source code for jQuery Tools 1.2.7?

Tags: jquery-tools

I need to get the source code for this, but unfortunately, I can't find links to it on jquerytools.org.  The forum on that site is also down.  Does anyone know where I can get this source or unminify it?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried going on http://jquerytools.org/download/? (I mean appending '/download/' to the url you posted)

EDIT: However you can download the source from [Git](https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools), got to the link and click "clone" or "zip".

EDIT: No, it's the 1.2.7 version, as you can see in the ["tag" link](https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/tags) they tagged the 1.2.7 version about 7 months ago, this is the version you need as far as I can read in your question, if you are not convinced than  I suggest you this link (that is the link near "Tagging version 1.2.7" in the github [project's tag page](https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/tags)):

https://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/zipball/v1.2.7

clicking on the link above you will start to download jquerytools v1.2.7 in a .zip file

Comment: Yes.  There used to be links for the source code there, but they aren't there now.

Comment: I added the link to the "jquery tools" repository on github.com

Comment: I don't think that's the right version.  It seems to be version 1.2.5.

Comment: I think that with the latest edit you should be able to solve your problem and flag my answer.

Comment: I downloaded it from a different location, but I am a bit concerned because the build file still says the version is 1.2.5.

Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately, building it didn't work.  Even if it had, I am concerned that I might not be dealing with the unminified version of what I have.

Answer (score 2):

It has become very difficult to find the source code for jQueryTools, and since the original CDN provided by the author has now disappeared a lot of sites that were calling the toolset from the CDN in question have stopped working.

There is a useful resource at https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-tools/1.2.7 that provides CDN/download links for all version of jQueryTools back to v1.2.0, which although it is not a source repository, can at least help some people with legacy sites still running to keep them running whilst they find an alternate solution or replace the website.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Revised answer is extremely useful. I thought I was doomed.